# How does SOFIA cope with open hull?

Tags: cabin-pressure, boeing-747

On the SOFIA aircraft, the aircraft is designed to fly at very high altitudes (higher than what can be achieved by regular 747), with a cargo door open.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/SOFIA_ED10-0182-01_full.jpg[image: Pic of sofia flying with open door]

I know that oxygen mask are a standard feature for most airliners but:

1. How is the aircraft designed to handle this situation ?
2. What about redundancy ?
3. If there is supplemental oxygen, is it really without adverse effects ?

pic credits wikimedia

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the picture I can see a bulk head forward of the telescope area. This modified 747SP might have a re-positioned bulk head then. Anything forward of the telescope would be pressurized.

[This source](http://www.cas.org.nz/threads/seeing-red-with-sofia.8/) confirms, bulk head was moved from the aft to be ahead of the telescope.

Comment: this tweet contains a nice visualization: https://twitter.com/SOFIAtelescope/status/747690813719777283